# Kalman filter: 3D measurement error to individiual components

Tags: kalman-filter, noise, precise-positioning

I'm working on a Kalman filter for estimating the position of a point in 3D space. I know that I can measure its 3D position directly with a variance of about 2 mm (in other words: the variance of the norm of the measured x, y, z vector is about 2 mm).

I'd like to fill my measurement noise covariance matrix based on this, so my question is:

How does this relate to the variance of the individual x, y, z measurements? I'm looking for three equal variances, assuming independency.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You can't touch the covariance matrix. It holds the uncertainty in your system.

Comment: I'm talking about the measurement noise covariance matrix R which the user should define, not the state error covariance matrix P.

Comment: you only define the sigmas at the start point. During the process, you shouldn't modify these matrices (i.e. the process and the measurement covariance matrices).

Answer (score 1):

Take a bunch of measurements of your system while states are static and compute the noise matrix yourself. As long as recording measurements is relatively straightforward this should be a painless process. It will also verify that your measurements are as accurate as you believe.